# Regular expression to detect line that starts with an asterisk

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

The code below fails to detect a single instance of the occurance. =O Whats wrong? =\

How do I detect the following lines (which begin with a newline) that begin with an asterisk ? I'm at a loss. This isn't behaving as I expected.

```
$text ="Nothing here to detect...though it is the first line.
* '' [[test]]
* Another line that starts with an asterisk 
** yet another...though it has two...but who cares about the 2nd one?";


$t = preg_match_all('#^\*.*#', $text, $match);
echo "found=".$t."\n";
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the `m` modifier to specify that this has a multi line subject like `#^\*.*#m`

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php